# How can I do a sentiment analysis on amazon lens?

Tags: amazon-connect

I am implementing a flow in amazon connect using amazon lens to perform sentiment analysis through voice

perform the configuration with set the behavior for recordings and analytics then set contact attribute and then you get customer input by selecting negative and positive score what I want to achieve is that when saying something bad or something good I refer to the corresponding flow and verify that it is correct what I said through voice